# fread takes a lof of memory when "skip" is large

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I have a large csv file (20G, almost 200million lines) which I cannot load to memory as a whole----> So I want to load it piece by piece.

I didn't find a way to use file connection in fread (like that in readLines)----> So I tried to use "skip":

```
for(i in 1:100){
lines=fread(filename,nrows=rowPerRead,skip=(i-1)*rowPerRead)
}
```

This works fine, at beginning. But it becomes slower as skip getting larger---in a nonlinear fashion. It turns out although those lines are skipped, it still takes a lot of memory during the process and only get cleaned when the process is done. And once the memory is used up, the process becomes very slow.

```
> system.time({newLines=fread("userinfo4.csv",nrows=1e6,skip=1,quote="") })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.71    0.04    0.73 
> system.time({newLines=fread("userinfo4.csv",nrows=1e6,skip=1e8,quote="") })
Read 1000000 rows and 12 (of 12) columns from 20.049 GB file in 00:01:47
   user  system elapsed 
  21.89   13.76  106.60 
> system.time({newLines=fread("userinfo4.csv",nrows=1e6,skip=1.4e8,quote="") })
Read 1000000 rows and 12 (of 12) columns from 20.049 GB file in 00:02:48
   user  system elapsed 
  16.95   12.49  169.76 
>
```

the memory usage for the 2nd and 3rd run. 
[image]

So my questions are : 
1. Is there a more memory efficient way to run fread with large skip? 
2. Is there a way to run fread from a file connection---so I can continue from last read instead of restart from beginning.

Comment: Have you tried to split the file into smaller chunks before loading it into R?

Comment: Yes, that's how I handled it. Unfortunately, I don't know any better tool to split the files so I used readLines+writeLines in R, which is much slower than fread.

Comment: On the command line you can use ‚split‘. Should be available or easy to install on Unix like systems. Might be more difficult on Windows.

Comment: you may already notice this from the img in the post, which is the task manager, I'm a stupid windows user....Probably that's why everything seems so difficult to me:)

Comment: Last time I had to use Windows I installed http://www.msys2.org/. Today https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 might be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ability of `fread` to accept a shell command that preprocesses the file as its input. Using this option we can run a gawk script to extract the required lines. Note you may need to install gawk if it is not already on your system (Linux and Unix-like machines usually have it already, on Windows you may need to install it).

```
n = 100   # lines to skip
cmd = paste0('gawk "NR > ', n, '" ', filename)
lines = fread(cmd, nrows = rowPerRead)
```

Comment: haven't tried it because gawk seems very powerful and I will need some time to get familiar with it. But using cmd definitely opens up a lot of possibility, so I will accept this answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue using `data.table::fread` to read in data as chunks while skipping rows. In my experience, adding a [garbage collection](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/gc) step helps with this problem. (Although R is supposed to automatically call `base::gc()` when memory is needed, for some reason with `data.table::fread` used in a loop, it appears to not work effectively.)

In your example code, it would look like this:

```
for(i in 1:100){
lines=fread(filename,nrows=rowPerRead,skip=(i-1)*rowPerRead)
gc()
}
```

Comment: interesting, Thanks for the information. I didn't know R has a gc().